# Inserting with loop in bash function

Tags: sql, bash, loops, hive, sql-insert

I have a source table, and I am trying to load it 10 times from the backup table but without duplicates in the id so with every load I want to add +1 to the id.

```
export mx=`hive -e 'select max(idp_row_id) from HISTDB_V3_NZ_HISTUSR.\`_hist_failed_authentication_3\`'`
for i in $(SELECT
`npsid`,
`npsinstanceid`,
`logentryid`,
`clientip`,
`sessionusername`,
`time`,
`failuretype`,
`failure`,
`tzoffset`,
`idp_delete_flag`,
`idp_batch_ts`
FROM HISTDB_V3_NZ_HISTUSR.`_hist_failed_authentication_3_backup`);
do
mx=$((mx+1))
hive -e '
INSERT INTO HISTDB_V3_NZ_HISTUSR.`_hist_failed_authentication_3`
(
`npsid`,
`npsinstanceid`,
`logentryid`,
`clientip`,
`sessionusername`,
`time`,
`failuretype`,
`failure`,
`tzoffset`,
`idp_delete_flag`,
`idp_batch_ts`
)
VALUES
(
'$mx',
`i.npsid`,
`i.npsinstanceid`,
`i.logentryid`,
`i.clientip`,
`i.sessionusername`,
`i.time`,
`i.failuretype`,
`i.failure`,
`i.tzoffset`,
`i.idp_delete_flag`,
`i.idp_batch_ts`
)
'
done
```

Is it possible that 'values' doesnt work in bash? (using putty)

Or do you see something wrong in the code?

Comment: Please check your code at https://shellcheck.net and if fixing those issues doesn't solve your problem then update your code above with the "fixed" code. Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Skip the version info at the top and read the sections "before asking about problematic code" AND especially "How to change a bad script into a good question" (or similar). We don't need to see 15 column names in your SELECT statment. Too big, make your code smaller. (-;! Good luck.

Comment: I don't understand your quesiton. `VALUES` is part of the SQL language and does not have anything to do with the language bash.

Comment: `SELECT` is also SQL, not bash, so `for i in $(SELECT ...` is unlikely to do anything other than cause a "command not found" error.